# Splitting a Character string in C programming

Tags: c, linux, string

I need to split a string and need to store in two seperate variables. The string contains a tab space. so it need to be seperated from the tab space

EG: the string looks like this

```
Sony <TAB>         A Hindi channel.
```

I need to store `Sony` in one variable say `char a[6];` and `A Hindi Channel` in another Variable say `char b[20];`

How can do this?

Comment: Is this C++ or C? Please decide.

Comment: Do you need to keep the tab characters, i.e. should `foo\tbar` result in `foo\t` and `bar` or in `foo` and `bar`? What about if there are two subsequent separators, e.g. `foo\t\tbar`.

Comment: check man pages for strtok

Comment: A dirty but simple solution would be to copy characters from the source string until you see the tab, skip it, and copy all the rest in another.

Comment: You should look at strtok() and do some effort yourself first. If you have problems getting it to work correctly, post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is that you are looking

Answer (score 1):

Tokenize string for a lot of programming language: [link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string)

In your case < tab > is a special character and it can be indicated as '\t'.

If you are using C programming language

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char *a[5];
  const char *s="Sony\tA Hindi channel.";
  int n=0, nn;

  char *ds=strdup(s);

  a[n]=strtok(ds, "\t");
  while(a[n] && n<4) a[++n]=strtok(NULL, "\t");

  // a[n] holds each token separated with tab

  free(ds);

  return 0;
}
```

For C++ without using boost library:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string s = "Sony\tA Hindi channel.";
  std::vector<std::string> v;
  std::istringstream buf(s);
  for(std::string token; getline(buf, token, '\t'); )
      v.push_back(token);
  // elements of v vector holds each token
}
```

Using C++ and boost: [How to tokenize a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int, char**) {
  string text = "Sony\tA Hindi channel.";

  char_separator<char> sep("\t");
  tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
  BOOST_FOREACH (const string& t, tokens) {
      cout << t << "." << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My C is old but something like that should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int getTabPosition (char str [])
{
    int i = 0;
    //While we didn t get out of the string
    while (i < strlen(str))
    {
        //Check if we get TAB
        if (str[i] == '\t')
            //return it s position
            return i;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    //If we get out of the string, return the error
    return -1;
}

int main () {
    int n = 0;
    //Source
    char str [50] = "";
    //First string of the output
    char out1 [50] = "";
    //Second string of the output
    char out2 [50] = "";

    scanf(str, "%s");
    n = getTabPosition(str);
    if (n == -1)
        return -1;
    //Copy the first part of the string
    strncpy(str, out1, n);
    //Copy from the end of out1 in str to the end of str
    //str[n + 1] to skip the tab
    memcpy(str[n+1], out2, strlen(str) - n);
    fprintf(stdout, "Original: %s\nout1=%s\nout2=%s", str, out1, out2);
    return 0;
}
```

Untested, but the principe is there

Comment: It is not worth computing `strlen(str)` at every iteration in the `while` loop which could simply be `while (str[i] != (char)0)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I didn t thought of that, I ve editted with your code. Thanks for the reminder.